# inheritance of a class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList
{

    public MyArrayList(String[] arr)
    {
        addarr(arr);
    }


    public MyArrayList(Integer[] arr)
    {   
        addarr(arr);
    }

    private void addarr(Object[] arr)
    {   
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        this.add(i,arr[i]);
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<this.size();i++)
        System.out.print(this.get(i).toString()+" ");
        System.out.println("");
    }

}


import java.util.*;
   public class TestMyArrayList
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
            String[] subjects = {"EIE320", "EIE558", "EIE375", "EIE424"}; 
            Integer[] marks = {90,85,70,80};
            MyArrayList<String> sList= new MyArrayList<String>(subjects); 
            Collections.sort(sList);
            sList.print();
            MyArrayList<Integer> mList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(marks); 
            Collections.sort(mList);
            mList.print();
       }
}
```

Complier: type MyArrayList does not take parameters

I know that I can solve the problem by editing

```
MyArrayList<String> sList= new MyArrayList<String>(subjects);
```

and

```
MyArrayList<Integer> mList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(marks);
```

to

```
MyArrayList sList= new MyArrayList(subjects);
```

and

```
MyArrayList mList = new MyArrayList(marks);
```

but how could I solve the problem by editing MyArrayList class but not the testing code?
Due to the minimum word of the post,I need to type more words there.

Comment: at first, add generics to your class, either let it generic or explicit as of `MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>` or `MyList extends ArrayList<String>`, for what it seems you´d like to use the first option here.

Comment: "Due to the minimum word of the post,I need to type more words there. " <- Or you could have taken that as a hint that you should describe your problem better. Anyway, you should probably start by reading what Generics are in Java and how they work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're extending the [raw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `ArrayList` type. If you want your class to be generic, you need to pass along the generic parameter like so:

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
```

You'll also need to modify your constructor to accept `E[]` instead of `Object[]`. The other constructors can be removed.